# Executing a UiPath activity from C# causes null pointer exception

Tags: c#, uipath

For `UiPath` version `18.2.3` I successfully created a new logging activity. The idea is, while logging everything in `Orchestrator`, the new activity would in addition log in a file as well. Coming up our organization will upgrade to `UiPath 2019.4.3` and my activity did not work, so I needed to upgrade the UiPath references to current `dlls`. Doing that gives me a compilable code, but the activity causes a `null-pointer exception`. Why?

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Activities;
using System.Activities.Presentation.Metadata;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using UiPath.Core.Activities;

namespace CustomCode.Log
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Designer attribute gives a look & feel like UiPaths own LogMessage activity
    /// </summary>
    [Designer(typeof(UiPath.Core.Activities.Design.LogDesigner))]
    public class LogMessage : CodeActivity, IRegisterMetadata
    {
        [Category("Input")]
        public CurentLogLevel Level { get; set; }

        [Category("Input")]
        public InArgument<System.String> Message { get; set; }

        [Category("Input")]
        public InArgument<System.String> LogFilePath { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// UiPath Log Message object reference
        /// </summary>
        private UiPath.Core.Activities.LogMessage _LogMessage { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public LogMessage()
        {
            DisplayName = "Extended Log Message";            
            Level = CurentLogLevel.Trace; // default setting
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// declare dummy register metadata class to force UiPath to load this assembly
        /// </summary>
        public void Register()
        {
            // intentionally empty
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// First log as if done by native UiPath then log to the file specified
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            // first do the usual UiPath logging...
            string message = Message.Get(context);
            //bool isNew = false;

            #region log as UiPath standard
            // it is necessary to create new objects every time. 
            // reassigning property values causes errors when logging is frequent...
            _LogMessage = new  UiPath.Core.Activities.LogMessage
            {
                Level = this.Level,
                Message = new InArgument<string>(message),
            };

            // do UiPath log 
            try
            {
                WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(_LogMessage); // NULL POINTER EXCEPTION HERE
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Internal UiPath Invoke Exception ", ex);
            }
            #endregion

            string logFilePath = LogFilePath.Get(context);

            // log to file if path is specified...
            if (logFilePath != null)
            {
                LogToFile(logFilePath, message, Level.ToString());
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method to write a line in the log file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename">the file to which to log</param>
        /// <param name="message">the log message</param>
        /// <param name="level">the log level</param>
        private void LogToFile(string filename, string message, string level)
        {
            StringBuilder LogLine = new StringBuilder(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
            LogLine.Append("\t");
            LogLine.Append(level);
            LogLine.Append("\t");

            LogLine.Append("\t - ");
            LogLine.Append(message);
            LogLine.Append(Environment.NewLine);

            try
            {
                // append the log line
                File.AppendAllText(filename, LogLine.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // try to log the exception in UiPath
                _LogMessage.Message = new InArgument<string>(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
                throw new Exception("Internal append to log file exception", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error indicates that **_LogMessage** is empty thus the null pointer error.

You can verify that by simply checking after the part of your code

```
_LogMessage = new  UiPath.Core.Activities.LogMessage
            {
                Level = this.Level,
                Message = new InArgument<string>(message),
            };
```

if your variable is empty:

```
if (_LogMessage.Any())
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I can confirm that the variable _LogMessage is not null.

Comment: Can you try and remove line Level = this.Level and try your code?

Comment: I did. The same null-exception still occurs.

Comment: how about Message = new InArgument<string>(message)?

Comment: Well, the whole idea is to execute the usual logging activity alongside with the new logging to a file. Without the message it has no purpose.

Comment: Yes trying to check the value that populates the null error. This is only to check if the error generates from this line.